# Cannot mount exFAT even installed exfat-fuse, exfat-utils in kali linux

Tags: linux, debian, mount, kali-linux

I formatted my usb in mac to exfat, but when i tried to use this usb in my kali linux `unknown filesystem type 'exfat'`

I already installed `exfat-fuse exfat-utils` but it's not working too, thesame error!

```
# sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdb1 /media/root/backup
mount: /media/root/backup: unknown filesystem type 'exfat'.
```

Answer (score 11):

I have the same problem on my Kali running release, exfat-utils & exfat-fuse installed. I tried rebooting, too. Could not mount, whether in dolphin or CLI.

From the OpenSUSE Forums: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/513961-exfat-installed-but-quot-unknown-filesystem-quot-at-mount-time

tried this :

```bsh
mount -t fuse -o subtype=exfat /dev/sdb1 /mnt/
```

and got a

```
permission denied
```

I finally found out that "mount" command doesn't know how to mount exfat, even when it is installed. But exfat-utils brings :

```bsh
mount.exfat-fuse /dev/sdb1 /media/exfat
```

and then it worked like a charm!
Hope it helps !

Comment: This also happens in Debian 11, and the workaround also works there.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this situation while mounting an SD card from a camera.

Fix was:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/sbin/mount.exfat-fuse /sbin/mount.exfat
```

Not entirely sure why `mount` can only resolve drivers(?) via `/sbin` and not `/usr/sbin`, but... Linux.

(Apparently there's also something called `exfatprogs` in the works, since `exfat` is available natively in the 5.7 kernel.)